# Subset of reals associated to pairs of matrices in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-actions

Let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. I would like to ask if there is any research on the following set:
$$\Gamma*\Gamma:=\bigg\{\dfrac{(a+b)(a'+b')}{(c+d)(c'+d')}\bigg|\begin{bmatrix}a&b \\c&d\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}a'&b' \\c'&d'\end{bmatrix} \in\Gamma,\;(c+d)(c'+d')\neq 0\bigg\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$$

ADD: The context of this question is related to a MathSE question: [Function on the Cartesian product of group-orbits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291150/).

Comment: Is this set supposed to live in $\mathbb P^1$, since you can get $1/0$? For that matter, what are you doing with the matrices that give $0/0$?

Comment: Thanks, I will not consider this case in general. I edited it. Now this set is supposed to live in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Saying that this is a subset of $\mathbb R$ does not make it so; you can still get $1/0$ or $0/0$.

Comment: You're defining a composition of two things. First define $u\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}=\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ assuming it's nonzero (say $\Gamma^*$ is the set of those matrices with $c+d\neq 0$). Then you're asking about the set $u(\Gamma^*)u(\Gamma^*)$. Is there one reason not to ask about $u(\Gamma^*)$? Could you give more context: Why are you interested in this subset? What kind of things would you like to know about it? What kind of subgroups $\Gamma$ are you interested in?

Comment: @YCor: I added the context of this question. I would like to know about the Lebesgue measure of the closure of this set, and when this value equals 1.